# Connecting NextJS, next-i18next, with-redux, with-redux-saga: "Error: If you have a getInitialProps method in your custom _app.js file..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, i18next

I'm trying to connect a functioning NextJS/React app that uses 'with-redux-saga' and 'with-redux' to 'next-i1iN' (https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) --  but when my app boots I get the following error:

> Error: If you have a getInitialProps method in your custom _app.js
>   file, you must explicitly return pageProps. For more infor  mation,
>   see: https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'namespacesRequired' of undefined
>       at Function.getInitialProps (/Users/cerulean/Documents/Projects/PAW-React/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/hocs/app-with-translation.js:94:57)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

But I am returning page props in my `_app.js`.

```
// _app.js
 static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {

    const pageProps = {};
    let temp;

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      temp = await Component.getInitialProps({ ctx });
    }
    Object.assign(pageProps, temp);
    return { ...pageProps };
  }
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with how I am hooking together the various HOCs?  In `_app.js` I have:

```
export default withRedux(createStore, { debug: false })(withReduxSaga({ async: true })(i18nInstance.appWithTranslation(MyApp)));
```

And in my `index.js` I have:

```
   // index.js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ homeData: getHomePageData(state) });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withNamespaces('common')(Index));
```

Any insights much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming to this issue and wondering what @cerulean meant in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577982/1498118).

#### 1) use `require` instead of `import`

NextJS doesn't transpile your modules if you use a custom server ([more info](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/196#issuecomment-467348442)). Therefore you cannot use `import` in your *next-i18next* configuration without going through a vale of tears.

```js
// NextI18NextConfig.js

const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next/dist/commonjs')

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  defaultLanguage: "en",
  otherLanguages: ["de"]
  // ... other options
});
```

```js
// server.js

const nextI18next = require("./path/to/NextI18NextConfig");

// ... the rest of your server.js code
```

This is a mix&match from **next-i18next** [example](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/9fdbefb903ed5b5ced2e1c8998511835cb754ead/examples/simple/i18n.js) and  [documentation](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/2f075270316aba841d5b661705abc6d5dddad810/README.md#3-project-setup)

---

#### 2) keep `pageProps` as it is

You cannot play too much with `getInitialProps` returned value. If you need to add extra stuff you should be careful not replacing or manipulating `pageProps`. See below.

```js
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    const extraStuff = doSomeExtraStuff()

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps, extraStuff }
  }
```

More about it on [this thread](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/124#issuecomment-456912659).

Answer (score 2):

If you have config redux sagas correctly, this way work for me:

```
export default withRedux(configureStore)(withReduxSaga(appWithTranslation(MyApp)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things for those who encounter a similar situation.

1) When they say 'return pageProps', it means 'return pageProps', not '...pageProps'

2) I was using ES6 import statements in the file which set up the 'next-i18next' singleton.  Needed to use 'require' and 'module.exports'

Now it works...